# Framework fails to link in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, xcode10

My App uses a static framework "A" (built as a dependency) which itself uses a static framework "B". In Xcode 9 this built and worked fine. In Xcode 10 I get "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" followed by a list of symbols referenced from "A" defined in "B". It appears the symbol definition exists in "A" but not the data. Xcode 9 includes the data in "A" but Xcode 10 does not.

Using Xcode 9:

```
nm -m -arch x86_64 "A" | grep "<symbol from B>"
                 (undefined) external _<symbol from B>
0000000000000f20 (__DATA,__const) external _<symbol from B>
```

Using Xcode 10:

```
nm -m -arch x86_64 "A" | grep "<symbol from B>"
                 (undefined) external _<symbol from B>
```

Why is this only failing in Xcode 10?

Comment: As shown in your [previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52425640/3),
`nm` is telling you that the `B` symbols are *referenced* but *undefined* in `A`.
Thus you need to link `B` to resolve those references and are not doing so. How you may have ceased to link
`B`, if you were previously doing so, is invisible from here.

Comment: Mike, I can switch between Xcode 9 and 10. Using 9, "A" contains the symbol data from "B". Using 10 it does not. Something has changed that causes Xcode 10 strip or not include the symbol data in "A".

Comment: That makes it clear, and you're right. Can't help I'm afraid.

Comment: It seems like the libtool command in Xcode 10 does not have frameworks listed in "Link Binary with Libraries" passed to it, and it does in Xcode 9.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2020 Xcode 12 edit:** While the original problem seems to have been fixed, this problem can still occur if the library B has an iOS Deployment Target lower than library A.

For some reason Xcode 10 does not pass the items listed in "Link Binary with Libraries" to libtool when creating the static library "A". This might be a bug or there might be some logic to it, I'll file a bug report. A workaround is to add the following to "Other Librarian Flags" in build settings for "A":

```
"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/B.framework/B"
```

Comment: Did you get any response on that bug report?

Comment: They closed as fixed in Xcode 10.2. I can't remember if it was fixed but I guess it probably was.

Comment: Thanks a lot BTW!